# The way with the variable name is not the same as the way with no variables?

Tags: python-3.x

```
s = requests.Session()
a1=s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789')


a2 = requests.Session().get('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789')
```

Why is  `a1 != a2`?
According to my understanding, a1 and a2 are equal, but in fact a1 and a2 are not equal?

Comment: consider accepting an answer, if a similar question is searched its more likely to be better understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same way would not work either:

```
>>> a1 =  requests.Session().get('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789')
>>> a2 =  requests.Session().get('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789')
>>> a1 == a2
False
```

That's because `request.Session().get()` returns a class instance

```
>>> type(a1)
<class 'requests.models.Response'>
```

You usually can't directly compare class instances, unless the comparison has been implemented in the class code.

You could compare the json responses:

```
>>> a1.json() == a2.json()
True
```

Answer (score 1):

With that comparrison you would compare the instances of your classes, not the values.

For better understanding:

> `a1` is a new instance of Session with some id (e.g. 12345) which requested some url
>
> `a2` is another instance of Session with some id (e.g. 56789), however not the same!

```
a1 == a2 is equivalent to 12345 == 56789
```

to compare the values, you have get set the variables to the output of your desired function. e.g.:

```
a1.json() == a2.json()
```